# 2D Персонаж встает на месте в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d, move

Пытаюсь разобраться с Unity, написал небольшой скрипт для передвижения персонажа

```
public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
public float MovementSpeed = 3f;
Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Run();
}

private void Run()
{
    float direction = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + 
(Vector3.right * direction * MovementSpeed)); 
}
}
```

Периодически, при нажатии кнопки передвижения, персонаж просто встает на месте, пока я не сдвину его в противоположную сторону.

Кто-нибудь может сказать в чем проблема?

Comment: Запустил ваш код, такой проблемы не возникло, попробуйте вместо `MovePosition` изменять `velocity` компонента `Rigidbody2D`. Возможно, из-за того, что `MovePosition` телепортирует объект, он застревает в другом коллайдере. Еще, строку `if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))` можете заменить на `if (direction != 0)`

Comment: Проблема была действительно в том что у меня было много коллайдеров, которые друг на друга наслаивались. Я сделал для них всех 1 большой и проблема решилась. Спасибо